# Provided Pipe doesn't have access to route resolved data

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-pipe, angular-providers

I have a pipe that needs to have access to route data in order to be well constructed :

```
export class LevelPercentagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  levelDictionnary: LevelDictionnary;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.levelDictionnary = new LevelDictionnary(this.route.snapshot.data['prerequisiteLists']);
  }
}
```

This data is resolved in routing module :

```
{
  path: 'xxx',
  loadChildren: './xxx/xxx.module#XxxModule',
  resolve: {
    prerequisiteLists: PrerequisiteResolver
  }
}
```

It works in other places of my application if the pipe is used in the html template.
But in this particular case I need to use this pipe in my `component.ts` file. So I provided it in the specific feature module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [LevelFilterPipe],
})
```

But now when it's injected in my component constructor it seems not to know about the data in the `ActivatedRoute`.

```
constructor(
        private profileService: ProfileService,
        private nameFilterPipe: NameFilterPipe,
        private levelFilterPipe: LevelFilterPipe
      ) {}
```

This doesn't work.

So instead I need to construct the pipe manually.

```
constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private scorePipe: ScorePipe,
    private nameFilterPipe: NameFilterPipe
  ) {
    // We have to inject route data and scorePipe manually because it's not injected automatically.
    this.levelFilterPipe = new LevelFilterPipe(this.route, this.scorePipe);
  }
```

Is there another way to inject the data from `ActivatedRoute` automatically?

Comment: This is the expected way on how pipes(services) work. Can you try providing it as dependency in the providers array?

Comment: @KiraAG it is already in the module providers array as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I meant providing ActivatedRoute as dependency to LevelFilterPipe in the providers array. Like mentiond [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers)

Comment: @KiraAG well if I understood correctly how dependency injection works, `ActivatedRoute` is already injected in the pipe ? by adding it in the constructor params it's supposed to be implicit, right ?

Comment: If the source info isn't available until the runtime , we may need to export it as factory provider. I have updated it with link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `pipe` to your component's providers list. Now your pipe injection will create a new instance of your pipe with the updated `ActivatedRoute` data.

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `...`:
  providers: [ YourPipeName ]
})
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-provide-pipe-in-component) example of your question. Take a look at the file `hello.component.ts`, this component is routed with a param like you've mentioned, remove the provided pipe in this component to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It indeed works! Thanks a lot. Can you explain why in this case we need to set this pipe into the `providers` list ?

Comment: If you look in Angular Docs [RouterStateSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterStateSnapshot) you will see that its description is `Represents the state of the router at a moment in time.` As I've mentioned in my answer, adding the pipe in the component's providers list will create a new instance of the pipe each time the component gets created. So in that moment in time the snapshot's data is updated, unlike when the app.module is providing it, meaning that the pipe was created in the first place with a snapshot updated to that moment in time, but when asked for the data is outdated

Answer (score 0):

Pipes aren't providers. Putting your pipe in the providers array of the component won't do much.

If you wish to make it work, you can simply create an instance of your pipe in your component and pass the current route.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  const pipeInstance = new MyPipe(ths.route);
}
```

You could aso try with injection in your pipe, something like this :

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ActivatedRoute)) private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

But I'm not sure this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Pipe is just another TypeScript class, it can be injected as a dependency if decorated with an `@Injectable()` decorator.

So your first approach is going to work if you add an `@Injectable()` above the pipe.

Something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
  name: 'level-filter'
})
export class LevelFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    ...
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Working StackBlitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-as-a-service?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

**PS:** Not quite sure if that is a good thing to do though.

Comment: You don't use ActivatedRoute data in your example. It still doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud, I'll have to create the whole example for that. Would you mind creating a Minimal StackBlitz sample and share it across? I can have a look into it and see where the problem actually is.